# If $a$ is positively correlated with $b$ then $b$ is positively correlated with $a$?

Tags: correlation

I believe that this question may have been asked before on this website, and so it might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything. Anyway, my question is that is there a formal word in statistics for the misconception that if $a$ is positively correlated with $b$ then $b$ is positively correlated with $a$?

For example, most politicians are rich, but not all rich people are politicians. Therefore, there is a positive correlation between politicians and money, but there's no strong positive correlation between money and politicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation is a symmetric dependence measure, meaning that $\rho(a,b) = \rho(b,a)$. It is the same both ways.

If, by intuition alone, it is believed that $\rho(a,b) \neq \rho(b,a)$, then $a$ and $b$ have an **asymmetric dependence**.

Comment: I looked up the word, and it is all used in the context of laws. Is the word actually a formal word in the language of statistics?

Comment: what search engine are you using. a search for asymmetric dependence immediately gives hundreds of economic policy and finance journal articles, both are statistical fields. The real term is "**statistical dependence**", which is in contrast to **statistical independence**. to be specific, **asymmetric (statistical) dependence** is a type of statistical dependence in contrast to **symmetric (statistical) dependence**. Correlation is not the only statistical dependence measure out there either.